# Angular 5 cli multi app service workers

Tags: angular, express, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have a multi app setup with angular cli, basically a client app and and admin app, with express to serve them. I was hoping to be able to serve the admin app from the admin path i.e `example.com/admin` which works fine until I add a service worker.

With service workers in place if I visit `example.com` then the app for `example.com/admin` will no longer load it always tries to load the client app from the service worker, unless I clear the cache and it then loads.

There is pretty much no documentation for the angular service worker implementation so have no idea if there are any options to overcome this.

Comment: BTW, the service workers are now enabled with the ng cli directly using the --service-workers command. try it. you will love it. The api still needs some improvement but this should help https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-service-worker-b722e571e306

Comment: Have the same issue, but with Wordpress blog which is on /blog route (